# structure array won't initialize

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to initialize the members of candy like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct CandyBar
{
std::string Brand;
float weight;
int cal;
};

int main()
{
CandyBar candy[3];
candy[0] = {"toe foe", 30.2f, 500};
candy[1] = {"lays", 2.1f, 10};
candy[2] = {"fin", 40.5f, 1000};
return 0;
}
```

But it gives me a syntax error near the opening brace
i know this is wrong but is there a way like this to initialize a array of struct.
And can someone explain why is the above code wrong.

Comment: Any reason for no constructor?

Comment: Your code works fine as-is in C++11.

Comment: @bames53, Huh, didn't think that worked with `std::string` as a member unless there was a constructor to call, but it does on GCC at least :)

Comment: **Your code should compile with C++11**.

Comment: @chris: In C++11, the many initialization rules has been relaxed/modified.

Comment: @Nawaz it will compile and work, on the other hand, it isn't initialization.

Comment: Here's a [compiling demo](http://ideone.com/0YkhM8).

Comment: @Nawaz It seemed hard for me to find any proof in standard. `n3242 5.17` about the assignment operator doesn't pointed such behavior.

Comment: @yuan there is nothing explicit in `5.17` assignment, but what I think happens is that copy assignment: semantically, the RHS initializar list converts to a `CandyBar` temporary, which is then used for assignment.

Comment: @Nawaz but I'm using visual studio 2012 and it does not compile

Answer (score 2):

```
CandyBar candy[3] = {
 {"toe foe", 30.2f, 500},
 {"lays", 2.1f, 10},
 {"fin", 40.5f, 1000}};
```

You can do this.

This style can only be used in the initialization stage, i.e when you create the variable. It cannot be used to assign the value later. (pre C++11)

Comment: You *can* use this style at the assignment stage too. `CandyBar` is an aggregate.

Comment: @juanchopanza any proof in standard? `8.5.1 Aggregates` didn't talk about the assignment at all

Comment: @juanchopanza I have made it clearer that the statement applies to < C++11. From the fact that the question exists, I take it thats where the OP is from.

Answer (score 2):

You're not *initializing* the array, you're making *assignments* to its elements.  If you *do* use an initializer, it will work fine:

```
CandyBar candy[3] = {
    {"toe foe", 30.2f, 500},
    {"lays", 2.1f, 10},
    {"fin", 40.5f, 1000}
};
```